# MVC - how to get the selected checkboxes in a list of checkboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello I've got a strongly typed view from this type

```
public class EditGroupModel
  {
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public List<PermissionChecked> Permissions;
 }
```

As you see my model has a List of type PermissionChecekd

```
public class PermissionChecked
  {
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set;  }
  }
```

And Here is my Strongly typed View

```
 @model EditGroupModel
    <div class="form-group clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-3">

                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GroupName, new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GroupName, new { @class = "form-control" })

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Permissions, new { @class = "control-label" })
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Permissions.Count(); i++)
                { 
                  @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.Permissions[i].Checked)
                  @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Permissions[i].Description)
                }
            </div>
```

**The problem is that when I post the data to the controller - as you may suppose the List with the PermissionChecked  items is null ()the model binding cannot work with List)  and I have no way of understanding which checkbox is checked or not
can you suggest a workaround which is the right way to do in this situation**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like adding a name for the checkbox. Something like "Permissions" and in the controller action that you call on form submission - you can have "List Permissions" in the action parameters to read the check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.
1.Associate some class with checkbox
and check what are checked or not using jquery.Then call the controller method using ajax.

2.Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KeoOPWshmw